# Why does jade file doesnt want to load CSS

Tags: css, node.js, express

I am trying to add login/register feature to my website using Node.js, so it will be saving users progress as he will be keep using website. But this question is not about node.js code, but more about .jade. I am not very familiar with jade and I just dont understand why it doesn't want to load my CSS file. And quick question: Is it necessary to use jade when you using a nodejs, or there is a way to use html instead of node?

layout.jade

```
doctype html
head
 meta(charset='utf-8')
 meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-
  to-fit=no')
 meta(name='description', content='')
 meta(name='author', content='')
 link(rel='icon', href='favicon.ico')
title Job Finder
// Bootstrap core CSS
link(href='public/stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
// Custom styles for this template
link(href='public/stylesheets/album.css', rel='stylesheet')
link(href='public/stylesheets/cover.css', rel='stylesheet')
link(href='public/stylesheets/path.css', rel='stylesheet')
#navbarHeader.collapse.bg-dark
.container
 .row
  .col-sm-8.py-4
    h4.text-white About Us
    p.text-muted
      text
  .col-sm-4.py-4
    h4.text-white Support Us
    ul.list-unstyled
      li
        a.text-white(href='#') Patreon Page
      li
        a.text-white(href='contactus.html') Email Us
    .container 
    block content 

       // Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster
script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js', integrity='sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=', crossorigin='anonymous')
script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js')
script.
  window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\\/script>')
script.
  window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/button.js><\\/script>")
script(src='public/javascript/popper.min.js')
script(src='public/javascript/holder.min.js')
script(src='public/javascript/bootstrap.min.js')
script(src='public/javascript/button.js')
// IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug
script(src='public/javascript/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js')
```

index.jade

```
 extends layout

block content
.navbar.navbar-dark.bg-dark
  .container.d-flex.justify-content-between
    a.navbar-brand(href='index.html') Job Finder
    button.navbar-toggler(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#navbarHeader', aria-controls='navbarHeader', aria-expanded='false', aria-label='Toggle navigation')
      span.navbar-toggler-icon
section.jumbotron.text-center
  .container
    button#btnSlideUp.btn.btn-outline-success.btn-sm.title
      h1#title.jumbotron-heading Find Job
    p#p1.lead.text-muted
      |text
    p
      a(href='contactus.html')
        button.btn.btn-outline-primary.btn-lg(type='button') Contact Us
      a(href='path.html')
        button.btn.btn-outline-secondary.btn-lg(type='button') Start finding a job
.album.text-muted
  .container
    .row
      .card
        a(href='path.html')
          img.card-img-top(src='pictures/photo-1494707924465-e1426acb48cb.jpg', alt='Card image cap')
          .card-body
            p.card-text How to start finding a job?
      .card
        a(href='path2.html')
          img.card-img-top(src='pictures/photo-1500015139098-84b51c349a60.jpg', alt='Card image cap')
          .card-body
            p.card-text Continue finding job
      .card
        img.card-img-top(src='pictures/photo-1495681803763-410ec9ff583d.jpg', alt='Card image cap')
        .card-body
          p.card-text
      .card
        img.card-img-top(src='pictures/photo-1498622205843-3b0ac17f8ba4.jpg', alt='Card image cap')
        .card-body
          p.card-text
      .card
        img.card-img-top(src='pictures/photo-1461773518188-b3e86f98242f.jpg', alt='Card image cap')
        .card-body
          p.card-text
      .card
        img.card-img-top(src='pictures/type-away-numero-dos.jpg', alt='Card image cap')
        .card-body
          p.card-text
      .card
        img.card-img-top(src='pictures/photo-1479920252409-6e3d8e8d4866.jpg', alt='Card image cap')
        .card-body
          p.card-text
      .card
        img.card-img-top(src='pictures/photo-1454165804606-c3d57bc86b40.jpg', alt='Card image cap')
        .card-body
          p.card-text
      .card
        img.card-img-top(src='pictures/photo-1501504905252-473c47e087f8.jpg', alt='Card image cap')
        .card-body
          p.card-text
footer.text-muted
  .container
    p.float-right
      a(href='#') Back to top
//
  Bootstrap core JavaScript
  ==================================================
script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js', integrity='sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=', crossorigin='anonymous')
script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js')
script.
  window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\\/script>')
script.
  window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/button.js><\\/script>")
script(src='public/javascript/popper.min.js')
script(src='public/javascript/holder.min.js')
script(src='public/javascript/bootstrap.min.js')
script(src='public/javascript/button.js')
// IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug
script(src='public/javascript/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js')
 link(href='public/stylesheets/album.css', rel='stylesheet')
link(href='public/stylesheets/cover.css', rel='stylesheet')
link(href='public/stylesheets/path.css', rel='stylesheet')
```

Comment: Are you in a base url "/" or in a subpath like "/login"? I